# Equation for points within a finite cylinder of arbitrary axial line.

Tags: geometry, rotations

If I have a finite length cylinder with axis along the line defined by points $P_1(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $P_2(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ in Cartesian space, how can I find a point $P(x, y, z)$ in Cartesian coordinates from the variables:

- $dl$: a distance from $P_1$ along the axis towards $P_2$
- $r$: a distance perpendicular to the axis line $P_1P_2$ (radius of the cylinder)
- $\theta$: the rotation angle around the axis line.

I have tried approaches similar to:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171110144434/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51734.html) and
the cylinder wiki page for arbitrary cylinders, but to no end.
http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node102.html for a rotation matrix approach, but I haven't been able to write down a generalized statement to handle all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find the distance $d$ from point $\vec{p}$ to the infinite right circular cylinder whose axis passes through points $\vec{p}_1$ and $\vec{p}_2$ using [point-line distance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html) (to the axis):
$$d = \frac{ \left\lVert \left ( \vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1 \right ) \times \left ( \vec{p}_1 - \vec{p} \right ) \right\rVert}{\left\lVert \vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1 \right\rVert}$$

We can use $t$ to denote the position along the axis (so that the line between that point and point $\vec{p}$ is perpendicular to the axis), with $t=0$ at $\vec{p}_1$, and $t=1$ at $\vec{p}_2$:
$$t = \frac{ \left( \vec{p} - \vec{p}_1 \right) \cdot \left( \vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1 \right) }{\left\lVert \vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1 \right\rVert^2}$$

Point $\vec{p}$ is within the right circular cylinder, if and only if
$$\begin{cases} t \ge 0 \\ t \le 1 \\ d \le r \end{cases}$$

Because the right circular cylinder is axially symmetric, there is no *"zero $\theta$ angle"* we can refer to. We must establish one ourselves.

Let's say we have an unit vector $\hat{c}$ ($\left\lVert\hat{c}\right\rVert^2 = \hat{c}\cdot\hat{c} = 1$) that establishes that zero angle for us. The vector must be perpendicular to the axis, i.e.
$$\hat{c} \cdot \left ( \vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1 \right ) = 0$$
If you have some generic zero angle vector $\vec{v}$ which is not parallel to the axis, you can calculate $\hat{c}$ in two steps, using
$$\vec{v}' = \vec{v} - \vec{v} \cdot \left( \vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1 \right)  \frac{\vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1}{\left\lVert \vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1 \right\rVert^2}$$
Note that $\vec{v}'$ is the original vector $\vec{v}$ with the axis-parallel-part subtracted from it; thus, it is perpendicular to the axis. We only need to normalize it to unit length to get $\hat{c}$:
$$\hat{c} = \frac{\vec{v}'}{\left\lVert\vec{v}'\right\rVert}$$

If we already know $d$ and $t$, we can easily construct an unit vector $\hat{q}$, from the axis towards point $\vec{p}$:
$$\hat{q} = \frac{\vec{p} + t \left ( \vec{p}_1 + \vec{p}_2 \right ) - \vec{p}_1}{\left\lVert \vec{p} + t \left ( \vec{p}_1 + \vec{p}_2 \right ) - \vec{p}_1 \right\rVert}$$
This unit vector is perpendicular to the axis (because that's how $t$ was defined), so the angle $\theta$ can now be easily calculated:
$$\begin{cases}
\cos\theta = \hat{q} \cdot \hat{c} \\
\sin\theta = \left\lVert \hat{q} \times \hat{c} \right\rVert
\end{cases}$$

When $\vec{p}_1$, $\vec{p}_2$, $\hat{c}$, $t$, $d$, $\sin\theta$, and $\cos\theta$ are known, we can calculate point $\vec{p}$.

First, we need a helper unit vector $\hat{u}$ which is perpendicular to both the axis ($\hat{u}\cdot\left(\vec{p}_2-\vec{p}_1\right)=0$) and the zero angle unit vector $\hat{c}$ ($\hat{u}\cdot\hat{c}=0$):
$$\hat{u} = \frac{ \hat{c} \times \left ( \vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1 \right ) }{\left\lVert \hat{c} \times \left ( \vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1 \right ) \right\rVert }$$

Then,
$$\vec{p} = (1 - t)\,\vec{p}_2 + t\,\vec{p}_1 + \hat{c}\,d \cos\theta + \hat{u}\,d \sin\theta$$

---

Years ago, I wrote some related equations to [my Wikipedia talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Nominal_animal), but never found the effort to try and push it anywhere more approppriate to be worthwhile. You might find it interesting or useful, though.

Comment: Thank you, this has given me more insight. However I am failing to see the final steps needed to get back a point in Cartesian space. In your notation, let's say that d and t are known, and theta is known with respect to some arbitrary unit vector c.

Comment: @voltnor: Oops, it seems I missed that part of the question somehow; I added that part to my answer.